# How to Insert values using Arabic?

Tags: android

I want to  develop an application by which we can insert values using English/Arabic.These values should be inserted or retrieved from  local/server storage.i googled for it .Unfortunately i did not got any clue about insert values using Arabic .Can any one help me to do it?

Comment: save all your values in string.xml and access them in your application by getResources().

Comment: plz..can you be more specific

Comment: thanks..may i know what is about your application? how you insert arabic values into databse?

Comment: Yes, you can insert arabic words in SQLite database column with type TEXT.

Comment: Please ask your queries here, I am in Office and they definitely not allow me to use personal email.

Comment: i just want to see  all alphabets in string.xml and the class file of your program

Comment: Brother i gave you the idea to get this thing done, Treat it like a simple string, Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this thing in my Arabic Application.

in my string.xml, I saved all alphabets of arabic.

```
<string name="Alif">ا</string>
<string name="Bay">ب</string>
<string name="jeem">ج</string>
<string name="Dal">د</string>
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.all alphabets in string.xml in Res folder of android project.
```

Now in my java class. I access them and use. like.

```
String Dal = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.dal);
String alif = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.alif);
.
.
.
.
.
```

NOTE:
When you combile 2 or more characters in android, Then Android itself make possible word, you no need to make words from combining different words.

Like if you combine ا, ح, م, د then android will automatically detect it and make word أحمد‎.

Hope this will helpful.